# In PHP, how do we get parent class variables?

Tags: php, class, variables, object

I was under the impression that child class inherit the properties of their parent. The following, however, is output null in class B... Can someone tell me how I access properties from the parent class?

```
$aClass = new A();
$aClass->init();

class A {

    function init() 
    {
        $this->something = 'thing';
        echo $this->something; // thing
        $bClass = new B();
        $bClass->init();
    }

}

class B extends A {

    function init() 
    {
        echo $this->something; // null - why isn't it "thing"?
    }
}
```

Comment: You have defined class A twice, and class B not at all... Are you sure this code is correect?

Comment: Did you mean `class B extends A`?

Comment: SOrry, that was a typo, I corrected it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. I've corrected them. The following script should work as expected. I hope the code comments are helpful:

```
class A {

    // even if it is not required you should declare class members
    protected $something;

    function init() 
    {
        $this->something = 'thing';
        echo 'A::init(): ' . $this->something; // thing
    }

}

// B extends A, not A extends B
class B extends A {

    function init() 
    {
        // call parent method to initialize $something
        // otherwise init() would just being overwritten
        parent::init();
        echo 'B::init() ' . $this->something; // "thing"
    }
}


// use class after(!) definition
$aClass = new B(); // initialize an instance of B (not A)
$aClass->init();
```

Comment: this will exhaust memory, since B will be instantiated infinitively

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Thanks for the hint! I haven't looked so close into the init function and overseen this

Comment: @hek2mgl - Thanks for the code. I see that calling "parent::init()" seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your second class defined should be `class B extends A`, and not `class A extends B`.

Comment: Even then that wouldn't be a solution. He'd override the init() method, so that the one from parent class is never called.

Comment: Right. He'd have to call `parent::init()` in class B's `init` function.

Comment: @xbonez - When calling init, will I only have access to variables defined in that function?

Answer (score 0):

We access parent class members in PHP using the following syntax:

`parent::$variableName`

Or

`parent::methodName(arg, list)`